# Issue with autoloading database and session libraries - codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, autoload

Right,

I was working on building a login system with codeigniter. It worked fine up until it started throwing up errors when trying to view the site. So I spent a few hours on Google trying to find out what could be wrong. I've managed to narrow the problem down to autoloading the libraries

The first error is:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

This corrects itself if I remove 'database' from the libraries array in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

The second error comes with autoloading sessions. The error is as follows:

```
The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.
```

Now, I'm not really sure about the sessions, but I know my database settings are fine.

I can, without any issue, pass data into my database when loading it manually in the model like so:

```
$this->load->database();
```

So my question is, why is autoloading all of a sudden throwing these errors? Does any one have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And your database.php config file? Is really up your db server? and the $autoload['libraries'] = array(); must have the 'database' lib to load

Comment: Some keywords cant be used as variable names..try a different variable name for config array..

Comment: @avenda yes my database config file is fine. Yes the database is up, Yes the autoload array had 'database' in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the appropriate Mcrypt extension with your web server. You can always add the following `extension=mcrypt.so` in your php.ini file if your server configuration supports it.

If everything was working fine before, It seems that you made a change in your server configuration that triggered the problem. As far as I know and encountered myself, CI 2 has some issues with php 5.6 that may produce these kind of errors. Try running a different version of php. Versions 5.3 or 5.4 are safe solutions.

Comment: Hi mate, I wondered if what you said was the issue, the thing is, it's not my server. It's a school server we're given access to so we can host our work. I'm not sure i'll be able to access the php.ini file or change version of php. That would have to be something an administrator does I imagine.

Comment: @bjurtown Can you provide your php version and if Mcrypt is indeed loaded with your php installation?

Comment: so the school server is running PHP Version 5.3.2
How would I go about checking mcrypt?

Comment: You can run a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and search for the Mcrypt information about the module. If its installed you will find it for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I did that to find out the php version, it also gave me a huge list of other details. I did ctrl-f "mcrypt" and nothing came up, so i'm assuming it doesn't exist. If this is the case then I probably have to get on to the server admins to update php

Comment: @bjurtown Exactly. By enabling mcrypt your problems with the Encrypt class should stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use new version of CodeIgniter 2.2.0

so please check on

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_220.html

or replace librarie Encrypt.php with old version librarie  in system\libraries folder

I think it should be work.